# Unable to change to landscape mode in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, netbeans

Since I made a lot of changes to the app, I am starting this thread to reflect them.  I am still having problems changing orientation.

Here's the code

```
Activity

    package com.flash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private ImageButton mPrevButton;
private ImageButton mNextButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank;
private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle)");
    setQuestionBank();
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
            == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        ProcessPortrait();
    } else {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
            == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.mainland);
        ProcessLandscape();
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessPortrait() {
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    updateQuestion();

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
    mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurrentIndex == 0) {
                mCurrentIndex = mQuestionBank.length - 1;
            } else {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            }
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
}

private void ProcessLandscape() {
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    updateQuestion();

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
}

private void setQuestionBank() {
    mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[]{
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true)
    };
}

private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getmQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].ismTrueQuestion();

    int messageResId = 0;

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_Toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_Toast;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
            == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ProcessPortrait();
    } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
            == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.mainland);
        ProcessLandscape();
    }
}
```

}

```
XML

Portrait

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/prev_button"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Landscape

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
                android:gravity="bottom|right"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

Manifest

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.flash"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0"
    >
        <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            <activity android:name=".QuizActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|
        keyboardHidden|screenSize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

When I debug using my phone, landscape works, although it may by my phone that is adjusting to the new orientation and not the app.

I am currently unable to get the debugger to work when using the emulator, so that is an issue I need help with as well.

When I run/debug the app, the home page displays and I have to press the recent apps button on the emulator and then double click on the app to bring it forward, hmmm, yet another issue.

Anyway, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question appears to be related to a previous one. Now beware: StackOverflow isn't a "forum style" system; people will not follow you from one question to another. If your original question has not been resolved but you have make progress toward it, please edit the original question, for example by appending description of your progress directly inside the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've moved the problem back to the original question

Comment: Eh... If it's removed, how can I see this? Have I been removed too? (but more seriously, please actually delete the question (should be next to edit), don't just edit the content)

Comment: Because as far as I know there is no way to actually 'remove' it.

Comment: If you listen to onConfigChanges="orientation" then your activity will not be recreated

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to fight against the system when an orientation change comes about.

1. I would suggest not overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` method.
2. I would suggest not checking what the orientation of the activity is in the `onCreate()` method.
3. Use [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) to determine what layout is used.

That all said when you rotate the activity this way the activity will be destroyed and recreated. Unless you have a big reason for not allowing the activity to be destroyed/re-created, I'd advise not handling orientation manually as you are. If you want to use orientation changes in this fashion you'll want to change your code to something similar to this:

First, rename your xml layout files to be the same name, eg `activity_quiz`. Then place them into different directories in your `res` folder like `res/layout/activity_quiz.xml` and `res/layout-land/activity_quiz.xml`.

Second change is to remove the `android:configChanges="orientation"` option. You can safely leave the other two `configChanges` options though.

Third change your activity code by removing the `onConfigurationChanged()` method completely. The system will handle that. And your `onCreate()` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setQuestionBank();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
}
```

Once you change your activity code, you should be able to merge your `ProcessPortrait()` and `ProcessLandscape()` methods into a singular method pretty much keeping your exact logic as it is now, just make sure to do a null check before accessing your views to ensure the app doesn't crash due to a `NullPointerException`.

You'll also want to look into state saving and restoration if you have data that needs to be saved/restored on orientation change, such as the count.

Hopefully this helps. If not I can try to clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried creating a layout-land folder, but it does not get compiled into R.java.  Any thoughts on this. I'll make the changes you suggested and see what happens. Again, thanks!

Comment: Is the `layout-land` directory at the same level that your `layout` folder is? Each directory should contain one `activity_quiz.xml` file each, the `layout-land` containing the landscape specific version. You might need to run a clean and rebuild your project completely if the app isn't being compiled properly.

Comment: I've made the changes, but now I can't rotate at all. It appears that it's going to work as the screen tried to render but then said the app stopped.  I'm using the getContentDescription for the mPrevButton. Is this a valid way of testing for null on an ImageButton?

Comment: I just did a clean and build. Now neither orientation works. Should I clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
The best way for you scenario would be to remove 
android:configChanges="orientation" from your manifest since you just want to change layouts during orientation.

    If you use android:configChanges="orientation" 
    then you must implement in activity like:

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // Handle Lanscape codes here
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            // Handle portrait codes here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have removed the code for that as it goes against android's good practices

Answer (score 0):

I installed some updates to the android sdk and when I ran the app, I got a message saying that the ant build xml imported from my project directory could not be found. Tried several things to correct. Waste of time. I decided to go back to using Android Studio, and now the app works in both landscape and portrait, each having their own layout.

Thanks everyone for all your help. We almost had it. My advice to netbeans is to stabilize their platform, as just about anything a developer does breaks it.

This question is officially closed